# Legend does not appear while using chart.js in react

Tags: reactjs, chart.js, chart.js2, chart.js3

I am creating a sales chart by year using react chart.js.

When the year button is clicked, the corresponding year data is brought from the server and the chart data is updated.

However, the legend in the upper part seen in the chart.js linechart example does not appear.

In the example, when you click the top legend, the chart is hidden and displayed, so that function is essential.

Please let me know what is the problem with my code below

```
class IndexYear extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.passData = this.passData.bind(this);
    }

    passData(e) {
        this.props.sendData(e.target.value)
        //console.log(">>1. selectYear" + e.target.value);
    }



    render() {
        const style = {
            margin: '15px',
            marginBottom: '50px',
            width: '100px',
            height: '30px'
        };

        const year = this.props.years;
        return (
            <input style={style}
                type="button"
                value={year}
                onClick={this.passData}
                key={year}
            />
        );
    }
}
```

If the new chart is outside the then of getOrderList() of componentDidMount(), the legend is visible. But when this happens, I can't put my data into the chart.

So it seems that new chart() must be in then.

### I want to be shown like this

[image]

### but reality

[image]

```
class LineChart extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        //console.log("1. constructor()");
        this.state = {
            orders: [
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [{ "chartDateText": "", "chartDateMonth": "", "chartStudentTotalCount": 0, "chartSpecialTotalCount": 0, "chartPremiumTotalCount": 0, "chartMasterTotalCount": 0 }], "indexYear": [] },
                { "orderCountChart": [], "indexYear": [] }
            ]
        };
        this.sendYearData = this.sendYearData.bind(this)
        this.ctx = null;
        this.chartRef = React.createRef();
        this.myChart = null;
    }

    componentDidCatch(error, info) {
        console.log("error : " + error);
        console.log("info : " + info);
    }


    sendYearData(year) {
        var year = year;
        var formData = { "selectYear": year }
        fetch("/Statistics/FindOrderSalesChart/", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(formData)
        })
            .then((response) => response.json())
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data)
                this.setState({
                    orders: data
                });
                this.myChart.destroy()
                this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {
                    type: "line",
                    data: {
                        labels: ["1월", "2월", "3월", "4월", "5월", "6월", "7월", "8월", "9월", "10월", "11월", "12월"],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [
                                this.state.orders[0].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[1].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[2].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[3].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[4].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[5].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[6].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[7].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[8].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[9].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[10].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[11].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount
                            ],
                            //data: [80, 100, 54, 70, 93, 100, 110],
                            label: "student",
                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                            backgroundColor: "#7bb6dd",
                            fill: false,
                        }, {
                            data: [
                                this.state.orders[0].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[1].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[2].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[3].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[4].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[5].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[6].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[7].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[8].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[9].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[10].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[11].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount
                            ],
                            //data: [70, 90, 44, 60, 83, 90, 100],
                            label: "special",
                            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                            backgroundColor: "#71d1bd",
                            fill: false,
                        }, {
                            data: [
                                this.state.orders[0].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[1].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[2].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[3].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[4].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[5].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[6].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[7].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[8].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[9].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[10].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[11].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount
                            ],
                            //data: [10, 21, 60, 44, 17, 21, 17],
                            label: "premium",
                            borderColor: "#ffa500",
                            backgroundColor: "#ffc04d",
                            fill: false,
                        }, {
                            data: [
                                this.state.orders[0].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[1].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[2].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[3].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[4].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[5].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[6].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[7].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[8].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[9].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[10].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[11].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount
                            ],
                            //data: [6, 3, 2, 2, 7, 0, 16],
                            label: "master",
                            borderColor: "#c45850",
                            backgroundColor: "#d78f89",
                            fill: false,
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        plugins: {
                            legend: {
                                display: true,
                                position: 'top'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
            })

    }



    componentDidMount() {

        this.ctx = this.chartRef.current.getContext("2d");
        //console.log("4. componentDidMount()");

        getOrderList()
            .then((response) => {

                this.setState({
                    orders: response
                })

                

                this.myChart = new Chart(this.ctx, {

                    type: "line",
                    data: {
                        labels: ["Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", "July", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"],
                        datasets: [{
                            data: [
                                this.state.orders[0].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[1].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[2].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[3].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[4].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[5].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[6].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[7].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[8].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[9].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[10].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[11].orderCountChart[0].chartStudentTotalCount
                            ],
                            //data: [80, 100, 54, 70, 93, 100, 110],
                            label: "student",
                            borderColor: "#3e95cd",
                            backgroundColor: "#7bb6dd",
                            fill: false,
                        }, {
                            data: [
                                this.state.orders[0].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[1].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[2].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[3].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[4].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[5].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[6].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[7].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[8].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[9].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[10].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[11].orderCountChart[0].chartSpecialTotalCount
                            ],
                            //data: [70, 90, 44, 60, 83, 90, 100],
                            label: "special",
                            borderColor: "#3cba9f",
                            backgroundColor: "#71d1bd",
                            fill: false,
                        }, {
                            data: [
                                this.state.orders[0].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[1].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[2].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[3].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[4].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[5].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[6].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[7].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[8].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[9].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[10].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[11].orderCountChart[0].chartPremiumTotalCount
                            ],
                            //data: [10, 21, 60, 44, 17, 21, 17],
                            label: "premium",
                            borderColor: "#ffa500",
                            backgroundColor: "#ffc04d",
                            fill: false,
                        }, {
                            data: [
                                this.state.orders[0].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[1].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[2].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[3].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[4].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[5].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[6].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[7].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[8].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[9].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[10].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount,
                                this.state.orders[11].orderCountChart[0].chartMasterTotalCount
                            ],
                            //data: [6, 3, 2, 2, 7, 0, 16],
                            label: "master",
                            borderColor: "#c45850",
                            backgroundColor: "#d78f89",
                            fill: false,
                        }
                        ]
                    },
                    options: {
                        plugins: {
                            legend: {
                                display: true,
                                position: 'top'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            })
    }



    render() {
        const rows = []
        const years = this.state.orders[12].indexYear
        years.forEach((year) => {
            rows.push(
                <IndexYear
                    years={year}
                    key={year}
                    sendData={this.sendYearData}
                />
            )
        })

        

        return (
            <div>                                   
                <div>
                    {rows}
                </div>                
                <canvas
                    id="myChart"
                    ref={this.chartRef}
                    options={{
                        plugins: {
                            legend: {
                                display: true,
                                position: 'top'
                            }
                        }
                    }}
                />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

```
function getOrderList() {
    return fetch("/orderSalesChart")
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then((data) => {
            return data;
        })
}
```

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <LineChart />,
    document.getElementById('content')
);
```